# Product page - How to move price block next to 'Add to Cart' button

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, price, product-page

What is the best way to move the price block down to the 'Add to Cart' button on a product page? It needs to be in line with the button. I've read various answers on google to do something similar but can't find exactly what my client wants.

Comment: Well that all depends on the theme. You can do it with 2 lines of css in the rwd theme. https://img1.picload.org/image/powgard/screenshot2015-10-27at16.32.55.png

Comment: @tecjam how would someone go about duplicating that price block instead of moving it? so having 2 on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

In your addtocart.phtml file

```
app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml
```

You can call price html

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>

<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What if we needed that price to change based on simple products?